# Taskbar Icon Gone Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

The rightmost icon on my taskbar is gone. I only have the Network, Battery, and Time/Date icons enabled. The time/date one is on the far right, and whichever one is directly left of it disappears, though there is still a space for it. When I expand the taskbar to two rows, the icon reappears in the second row. How can I convince the icon it belongs in the first row?

I have TranslucentTB installed.

[Missing Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWHjB.png)

[Woah It's Back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idWpN.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96444/discussion-on-question-by-j-dandy-taskbar-icon-gone-windows-10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click on the Taskbar > Taskbar settings >Notification area > Select which icons appear on the taskbar >Toggle off on the desired icon.

Comment: The space disappears, but I then don't have the icon I want

Comment: are you using multiple displays ?

Comment: check this link....check the replies too
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-taskbar-icons-gone/c27abf56-9703-40f0-9d82-6c48ee689b1f

Comment: Make a new user account on your PC and log in to that acc, might be an account issue